# How do I find the location of a page?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-pages

I have a contact page that is not in cms pages. It has a static block that is only used on this page. I can edit it and see it, but can not find the page. Any suggestions on how to track it down? Is there a way to search for the static block in the code somehow?

Comment: store is live ?

Answer (score 0):

on the devloper mode in backend so you can find out which page is call.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the system admin panel then System > configuration.

Set default configuration scope to main website.

Then Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

Open you page and you will see the hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can it in the Magento admin panel: System > configuration.

Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

and here you can find each detail of the pages which have been called.